# Meaning of the expression in xslt

Tags: xslt-2.0

On my xslt code i have the following code, but, I could make it what it actually mean:

```
<xsl:template match="leg:Primary | leg:Secondary | leg:Body | leg:Schedules | leg:SignedSection | leg:ExplanatoryNotes | leg:P1group | leg:Title | leg:Group | leg:Part | leg:Chapter | leg:Pblock | leg:PsubBlock | leg:P1 | leg:P |leg:PrimaryPrelims | leg:SecondaryPrelims | leg:Schedule | leg:Form | leg:Schedule/leg:ScheduleBody//leg:Tabular " mode="ProcessAnnotations">
<xsl:param name="showSection" as="element()*" tunnel="yes" select="()" />
```

Here on the `param` the entered value is `()`, what it is mean? pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value set by the `select="()"` attribute is an empty sequence.

Answer (score 1):

IMO it is an empty set of elements, i.e. when there is no value passed into this param, the default value is empty set.

Comment: Close, but not exact: it is an empty sequence. In XSLT 2.0, everything is a sequence, and `()` displays nothingness ;).